# Service takes too much memory

Tags: java, android, service

I have a service that extracting html code from an URL, converting it to text only (with Jsoup) and then checks something on the string, and if some conditions are true it launches a notification and writes something to a file.
As far as I know, this kind of service shouldn't take much memory, and in Watchdog, it takes ~65 MB, and it is way too much. It takes more than any other process (even more than tw launcher and Android System).
I would like you to tell me what have I done wrong.

Heres my service class:

```
public class NotifyService extends Service 
{
    private int number=0;
    private Timer timer=new Timer();
    private long INTERVAL=1*1000*60*60;//1 hour

    public static String Oldhtml;
    public static String Newhtml;
    public static String currHtml;


    // hooks main activity here    


    /* 
     * not using ipc...but if we use in future
     */
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
      return null;
    }

    @Override 
    public void onCreate() 
    {
      super.onCreate();     

      _startService();
      Log.w("myApp", "START");
    }

    @Override 
    public void onDestroy() 
    {
      super.onDestroy();

      _shutdownService();
      Log.w("myApp", "STOPPED");

    }


    /*
     * starting the service
     */
    private void _startService()
    {      
      timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        public void run() {
            try {
                doServiceWork();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(INTERVAL);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    },0,INTERVAL);
      ;
    }




    /*
     * start the processing, the actual work, getting config params, get data from network etc
     */
    private void doServiceWork() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException
    {
        String FILENAME="blichData";
        String info=null;
        String classLetter = null,classNum1=null;
        int classNum = 0;
        try{
            FileInputStream fis=openFileInput(FILENAME);
            byte[] dataArray = new byte[fis.available()];
            while(fis.read(dataArray)!=-1)
            {
                info = new String(dataArray);
            }
            classLetter = info.substring(0, info.lastIndexOf(" "));
            classNum1 =info.substring(info.lastIndexOf(" ")+1);
            classNum=Integer.parseInt(classNum1);
            fis.close();
        }catch (Exception e){

        }
        if (classLetter!=null && classNum1!=null) {
            Oldhtml=readHTMLfromFile();
        if (GetHTML.isHavingChanges(classLetter,classNum))
        {
            myNotify();
            writeHTMLtoFile(currHtml);
            /*
            try {
                String data= "false";
                FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("blichService", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                fos = openFileOutput("blichService",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                fos.write(data.getBytes());
                fos.close();
                }
                catch (Exception e) {}
                */
        }
        }
;
        }



    /*
     * shutting down the service
     */
    private void _shutdownService()
    {
      if (timer != null) timer.cancel();
      Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Timer stopped...");
    }
    public void writeHTMLtoFile(String html) {
        try {
            String FILENAME = "blichNotifyData";
            String data= html;
            FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            fos.write(data.getBytes());
            fos.close();

        }
            catch (Exception e){}
    }
    public String readHTMLfromFile() {
        String FILENAME = "blichNotifyData";
        String info="";
        try{
            FileInputStream fis=openFileInput(FILENAME);
            if (fis.available()>0)
            {
            byte[] dataArray = new byte[fis.available()];
            while(fis.read(dataArray)!=-1)
            {
             info = new String(dataArray);
            }
            fis.close();
            }
        else {
            Oldhtml="null";
        }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {}
        return info;

}
    public void myNotify()
    {
        NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Intent intent= new Intent (this,SchoolBlichActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        String body = " בליך";
        String title = "ישנם שינויים חדשים!";
        Notification n =new Notification(R.drawable.table, body, System.currentTimeMillis());
        n.flags |=Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        n.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), title, body, pi);
        n.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;
        number++;
        n.number=number;
        nm.notify(0,n);


    }

    }
```

And if it is needed, the HTML extracting class:

```
public class GetHTML {
    public static boolean isHavingChanges(String classLetter,int classNum) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
            int classLetterCode = 0;
            int timeTableCode=1;
            if (classLetter.equals("ט"))
                classLetterCode=0;
            else if (classLetter.equals("י"))
                classLetterCode=1;
            else if (classLetter.equals("יא"))
                classLetterCode=2;
            else if (classLetter.equals("יב"))
                classLetterCode=3;
            switch(classLetterCode)
            {
            case 0:
                if (classNum>=1 && classNum<=7)
                    timeTableCode=1;
                else if (classNum>7 && classNum<=14)
                    timeTableCode=2;
                break;
            case 1:
                if (classNum>=1 && classNum<=7)
                    timeTableCode=3;
                else if (classNum>7 && classNum<=14)
                    timeTableCode=4;
                break;
            case 2:
                if (classNum>=1 && classNum<=7)
                    timeTableCode=5;
                else if (classNum>7 && classNum<=14)
                    timeTableCode=6;
                break;
            case 3:
                if (classNum>=1 && classNum<=7)
                    timeTableCode=7;
                else if (classNum>7 && classNum<=14)
                    timeTableCode=8;
                break;
            }
            String url = "http://blich.iscool.co.il/DesktopModules/IS.TimeTable/MainScreen.aspx?pid=17&mid=6264&page="+timeTableCode+"&msgof=0&static=1";
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

        String html = "";
        InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            str.append(line);
        }
        in.close();
        html = str.toString();
        html = Jsoup.parse(html).text();
        if (NotifyService.Oldhtml.equalsIgnoreCase(html)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (timeTableCode%2!=0){
            for (int i=0;i<8;i++) {
                if (!html.contains(i+" "+i)) {
                    NotifyService.currHtml=html;
                        return true;
                    }

                }
            }

        if (timeTableCode%2==0) {
            for (int i=8;i<15;i++) {
                if (!html.contains(i+" "+i)) {
                    NotifyService.currHtml=html;
                        return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
}
}
```

Ignore the foreign language. xD
I just want to understand what have I done wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I cannot tell out-of-the-box what portion of your code is problematic, you may try to analyze the memory usage through a heap dump taken with DDMS using Eclipse MAT. You will need to use the `hprofconv` tool to convert your Android heap dump into a format that MAT understands.

To get the HPROF Heap Dump, open the Dalvik Debug Monitor (DDMS), connect it you your emulator, select the process of your application and hit the "Dump HPROF file" icon.

Comment: Im sorry but I didn't understand... can you explain me how to do this?

Comment: I recommend the [Memory management for Android Apps](http://www.google.com/events/io/2011/sessions/memory-management-for-android-apps.html) session from this years Google I/O. A lot of this stuff is explained and shown there, including basic usage of MAT.

Comment: user974485: I added some basic information to my answer. For further details, the video referenced by alextsc is certainly a good start.